# Unity 2D Game Dev - Converting PSD to PSB without Photoshop

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, sprite, skeletal-animation

So there is a feature in Unity that supports importing PSB files as 2d characters:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.2d.psdimporter@1.2/manual/index.html

(even though it only work with PSB, for some reason it's called PSD importer)

So I made a simple stick man in Krita to use for my new game, and then I noticed that Krita doesn't let me export as PSB! Not only that, even GIMP doesn't support PSB!

I don't have Photoshop, so is there a way to convert the PSD that I have to PSB without Photoshop?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found out that you can just rename the .PSD file to .PSB and it will work! Awesome!

Source: https://forum.unity.com/threads/psd-importer.591532/#post-4163995

Comment: I'm not so sure about that. I had the same problem earlier and found that changing the file name did not work and caused the file to not be imported. I ended up using a tool called ImageMagick to convert the psd file.

Comment: It's working perfectly! Thanks! Just make sure you have the 2D PSD Importer installed from the Package Manager.

Answer (score 1):

This it what works for me at the moment. Create character in krita with layers. Export to psd. Open psd in gimp. Export to psd from gimp. Rename resulting psd to psb. Import into unity. Not sure why but just renaming psd made by Krita to psb does not work. Something about the way Gimp exports to psd seem to work differently.

I known that the psd (very early version ) importer for unity is on github. I have thought of maybe taking a look at the source code and creating a fork . Any one game to try and fix this? I may be in over my head but maybe some team work will get us there.

Here is something else that works for me in a pinch. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZtpACxCTEE

This involves using a flat png ( just put arms , legs head etc away from body. Import sprite as single not multiple.
Rest of the video explains everything clearly. Setup is about the same amount of work as psb import.
Hope someone finds this useful.

Answer (score 0):

There is a site which you can drag the psd file and it will make the changes for PSB.
https://www.imageconvert.org/psd-to-psb